# MySQL: please help me, this is my code and CHECK tag doesnt work for me

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Code to create table: There is an error here.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
user_id INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
mname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
usn INT(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
sched VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHECK(sched IN ('morning','afternoon')
);
```

Comment: None of MySQL storage engines support check constraints.  You may emulate them using triggers, q.v. the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `OR`

```
CREATE TABLE students 
(user_id INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
 mname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 usn INT(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 sched VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHECK(sched ='morning' OR sched ='afternoon'));
```

Comment: still doesnt work :(

Comment: What is the mysql version? This is sample link(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/275d820/1). Looks like None of MySQL storage engines support check constraints(https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work). You may have to use a different approach to enforce the constraint.